# How to execute single test class/method in JUNIT in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to execute the JUNIT test for my project and it takes nearly 30 mins to complete the test.
How to run only single test class/method in JUNIT test?

Answer (score 3):

Right click and run as on the single method or put @Ignored annotation on the methods you want to avoid

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Is it available in it.

Comment: Yes =) , run as -> junit test

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one class and if you use Eclipse, then right click on the .java file -> Run-As -> JUnit Test.